# detecting if a chess move is valid for a given pawn , preferably using Linear algebra

Tags: movement, linear-algebra, chess

I'm making a chess game, where you simply drag and drop a pawn on the board with respect to each player's turn.
when it comes to dropping a pawn we need to validate weather the move is allowed. for some reason my very first instinct was to use linear algebra, particularly finding out if the new position is within the span of a given pawn.

now each pawn is given :

1- a set of vector movements e.g a queen's movement =(0,1),(1,0),(1,1);

2- a magnitude of movement e.g a queen can only move a single block a turn i.e magnitude =1

3- a direction i.e if a pawn can move back and forth  then direction=-1 else direction =1;

using Gauss elimination we can check weather or not the new position is reachable given the pawn's set of movements but it disregards it's current position. e.g using Gauss elimination the position (4,5) is reachable by a queen pawn given it's set of movements. BUT only if the queen is 1 block away.

how to take the current position of a pawn while checking for the new positions validity using linear algebra and Gauss elimination?

Comment: Are we really talking about the same [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), an algorithm for solving systems of linear equations? What system of linear equations are you trying to solve in chess rule set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply separate each piece's logic, then every time the user attempts a move, do something like `IsValidMovement(from, to)`. When it comes to the Rook, if `from` and `to` have the same X or the same Y, it's a valid move (but then you have to check for other pieces obscuring the way). Assuming that you use a language that supports OOP, you can do that in a form of subclass.

Using vectors is not wrong, but it becomes cumbersome and could potentially require too much manual work, the bishop's movement can be automated, you don't have to save all individual blocks that it can move to. Also the knight can jump over pieces, while others cannot. The pawn also has special behaviour when near enemy pieces.

Here's an example in pseudocode:

```
class BaseClass {

    // Data that all pieces have

    bool abstract IsValidMovement(Vector2 from, Vector2 to);

}

// Subclass for the Rook piece
class Rook : BaseClass {
    bool IsValidMovement(Vector2 from, Vector2 to);
}

// The user made a movement starting from `from` and ending at `to`
bool Rook::IsValidMovement(Vector2 from, Vector2 to) {
    /* The rook can only move either horizontally or vertically
     * as many squares as it likes (without obstacles)
     */
    if ((from.x == to.x) || (from.y == to.y)) {
        // The rook made a movement which is valid
        return true;
    }

    // The target square is not in reach
    return false;
}
```

Now when you create the pieces, you can do something like `Rook rookLeft = new Rook();` and when the user makes a movement, once they place the piece on the board you can do `rookLeft.IsValidMovement(originalPosition, endPosition);`. If it returns true, the piece can move there, if it returns false, the piece cannot move there.

If you want to check for obstacles, like a piece being in between, you can also add one more argument (maybe an array of pieces?) and include that in your logic. In the example of Rook, if the end position is three squares to the right of the rook, it's a valid movement, but if there's another piece one square to the right, then it's not.

Comment: hey tom,you right I think a simple vector calculation is what I'm looking for, can you elaborate on your method further?

Comment: @RaedTabani I edited my answer